# EXT JS - How to add a prompt message in Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

**Please explain these steps in full details**

How to write code for these lines .

- Add empty cell prompt "Manually input prices if not selected"
- Filter pick-list on estimatingMethod.pricing = true
- On selection if quote.contractType <> null and edtimatingMethod.contractType <> null and quote.contractType is not IN list of estimatingMethod.contractType then give warning message "Contract type in CLIENT tab xxx does not match selected pricing strategy contract type YYY"

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of fiddles that show how to do this stuff.  Also the documentation. And the examples like the kitchen sink.
This is not a "I am stuck on something" question.  This is a please write my software.

Take a look at the store filter method. You fill a pick list with a store and filter it.

The placeholder property of a text field will show in an empty field.

Take a look at field validation in the examples for how to show a warning messages based on selections.
[Link showing validation and also placeholder.](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#field-validation)

Comment: I get the initial 2 points but dont know how to code for the third point. Do i need to define a listener and then define it in controller with the if loop condition.

Comment: There is a validator property on textfield that is a function.  you can add your code there or reference a function.  Also the model class has a validators array that is an array of objects of the Ext.data.validator.Validator class to validate fields based on the model.